# Make certain programs in Xfce not go to the Notification Area

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel

When I run Xfce Task Manager, it shows a little icon in the Notification Area on my Panel. To close the program, I right click on the icon and select Quit. Other programs work in this way also such as Notes. Is there a way to launch these so they do not go to the Notification Area? I want to be able to Quit the program when I close the window as it is with other programs. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes care of the issue. I set this script to run from Whisker Menu instead of just Task Manager. It launches Task Manager and records its PID. Every five seconds it checks if the Task Manager window is still open. If it is closed, it kills the program and exits the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

xfce4-taskmanager & taskmgr_pid=$!

while true; do
    sleep 5 
    status=$(wmctrl -l | grep "Task Manager")
    if [ -z "$status" ]; then
        kill "$taskmgr_pid"
        exit
    fi
done
```